# Call Object in another Function

Tags: php, oop, object, methods

I have 2 function like:

```
public function x(){
    $i = 10;
}

public function y(){
    $j = $this->x();
    var_dump($j);die;
}
```

How to call object `$i` in another function y?

Comment: a) $i is not an object, but an integer. b) you have to `return` it. otherwise x() returns NULL.

Comment: oke. I change $i an string value or an array. how to call it in another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1** (Object oriented)

```
class MyClass {

    $i; // instance variable

    public function x() {
        $this->i = 10;
    }

    public function y() {
        $this->x(); // initialize instance variable
        var_dump($this->i); // use instance variable
        die;
    }
}
```

**Solution #2**

```
public function x() {
    return 10;
}

public function y() {
    $j = $this->x();
    var_dump($j);
    die;
}
```

Comment: if $i a string or array? its is same solution?

Comment: Sure, it should works, but keep variable type safe. Avoid returning 10 if it's a string or an array :)